# Unable to convert list to dictionary in python3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to convert an array list to a dictioanary. Below is the code:

```
arrayList=[{"userId":580518,"jobTitleName":"CNC Operator","firstName":"Rosa","lastName":"Spencer","preferredFullName":"Rosa Spencer","employeeCode":"553},
{"userId":523820,"jobTitleName":"Health Educator","firstName":"Carmella","lastName":"Morrison","preferredFullName":"Carmella Morrison","employeeCode":"713-44-3665"}
]

dictValue= {}
for row in arrayList:
   dictValue=eval(row)
print(dictValue)
```

It only print the last row ie- userId":523820 from dictValue, and other values are not seems to be added in to the dictionary
I know the row is returning as string, but even i tried different way to convert string to dictionary that also not working
Appreciate if anyone can help on this

Answer (score 0):

You need to collect all elements of list. Instead, you are just replacing previous value after each iterations

Answer (score 0):

Instead this `dictValue=eval(row)` use this `dictValue.update(row)`

Comment: Hi @Evgeniy.. i tried with the above code, but still it returns only the last value

Comment: @umdev sorry. Instead `eval(row)` try `row`. Like `dictValue.update(row)`

Comment: Hi @Evegeniy, yea i tried with same code you suggested, dictValue.update(eval(row)).. but still it returns last row value

Comment: Oh, I get it. Problem is here. Yours array contained two dictionaries. These two dictionaries having same keys, so you cannot add this two into single dictionary, because last dictionary always rewriting previous values.